# Angular how to ngFor the nested object properly?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a JSON object like this in our API:

```
{
   "count": 58,
   "next": //API URL OF THE NEXT PAGE CUS WE HAVE PAGINATION HERE
   "previous": //API URL OF THE PREVIOUS PAGE 
   "results": [
     {
      "game_id":3,
      "title":"Basketball"
     },
     {
      "game_id":4,
      "title":"Football"
     }
     //THE LIST GOES ON AND ON LIKE THIS
   ]
}
```

So I have a class like this;

```
export class TheGames{ 
    count:number;
    next:string;
    previous:string;
    public results = new class {
        game_id:number;
        title:string;
    }
}
```

In my ts file I subscribe them like this;

```
 game: TheGames[];
 //gameandcatservice is the service that I use and get games returns the games from API
  this.gameandcatservice.getGames().subscribe(data=>{
    this.game=data;
```

In html file I went like this;

```
<div *ngFor="let g of game['results']">
   <!-- SOMETHING HERE -->
</div>
```

I get the error of inside the console at browser;

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined at....
```

I ont know why this happends because I have already defined results in the class and when I do this, I can acces to the elements inside results and print them to screen.

EDIT: Here is my getGames() function in service file;

```
  getGames():Observable<TheGames[]>{
    return this.http.get<theGames[]>(this.pathGames);   
  }
```

Also when I console.log(this.games), I get  result like this;

```
    count: 58
    next: "http://localhost:8000/api/games?page=2"
    previous: null
    results: Array(10)
    0:
    game_id: 3
    title: "Basketball"
    __proto__: Object
    1:
    game_id: 8
    title: "Football"
    __proto__: Object
   //LIST GOES LIKE THIS FOR 10 ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change your class to

```
export class TheGames { 
    count: number;
    next: string;
    previous: string;
    results: {
        game_id: number;
        title: string;
    }[];
}
```

Besides this, you assign `this.game` in an async manner. When the component is created `this.game` is undefined until the callback run. So you will need to handle this pending state.

One possibility would be to add the save navigation operator

```
<div *ngFor="let g of game?.results">
   <!-- SOMETHING HERE -->
</div>
```

Comment: Also, do people usually use classes instead of interfaces for models? Why? Seems unnecessary, it just adds code to the compiled javascript with no added benefit

Comment: I am kind of a new programmer at Angular, so didnt really understand how can I handle what you have said :/ Can you please explained it with a little bit more detailled?

Comment: I extended my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the error by using `?` [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator) .The Angular safe navigation operator, `?`, guards against null and undefined values in property paths

```
<div *ngFor="let g of game?.results">
   <!-- SOMETHING HERE -->
</div>
```

also you have a typo in your code, wrong class name `theGames[]` :

```
 getGames():Observable<TheGames[]>{
    return this.http.get<TheGames[]>(this.pathGames);   
  }
```

here is a working [stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff1esk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I have tried that but still get the same error in console

Comment: @Michael also post your service function `getGames()` here

Comment: @JoelLoseph I have posted my console.log and getGames function in the edited version of my question

Comment: @Michael you have a typo in you class name, see my updated answer with demo

Comment: @Michael did you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use an async pipe instead. Like so:

Component.ts

```
 game: this.gameandcatservice.getGames().pipe(
     take(1)
 )
```

Component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let g of (game | async)?.results">
   <!-- SOMETHING HERE -->
</div>
```

This will give you the added bonus of not having to unsubscribe from your observable if you would have needed to, and you won't have to initialise your variable, nor type it (it will infer its type from `getGames` on your service.)